# How do I create a Reusable/Global Button Component in Nuxtjs or vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, button, nuxt.js, reusability, code-reuse

We've all been here. Good code avoids repetition. If you repeat the same code in more than one file, how about making it a component? Use your own threshold/judgement to measure if the code really needs to be a component.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take you through how to create a Global(component that can be used app-wide) button component in NuxtJs but can also apply for Vue.js.

First create the component file in your components directory, in my case `PrimaryButton.vue`. The code inside my PrimaryButton component looks something like this

```
<template>
  <button class="rounded-button-cyan subheading4" @click="callback($event)">
    {{ buttonText }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    buttonText: String,
  },
  methods: {
    callback: function (e) {
      this.$emit("click", e);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In the above snippet we have created a global PrimarButton that can take in a prop `buttonText` and a click event as well.

So let's now use it.
We can now use the button in any file like...

```
<template>
  <PrimaryButton  @click="showAlert()" buttonText="Show Alert" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    showAlert() {
      alert("EARTH HACKED ");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```